# sql server: select either conditions using an OR clause?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a Products tablet; in that there are a couple of fields like subcatid and designerid, which are coming from a Subcategories and Designers tables respectively. The website (ASP.NET C#) admin can insert some kind of Coupon Codes in a CouponCodes table by selecting either a designerid or a subcatid or both. This means that a particular product can be sold cheaper if either designerid or the subcatid fields or both for that product is found inside the CouponCodes table. Note, a Product does not necessarily have a designerid or a subcatid: An Admin can enter 'N/A' for either as Product is entered; the N/A has designerid of 27 and a subcatid of 9 in their respective tables. Probably not the best database design.

Anyway, here is my code in SSMS; when I try execute it I get an error of syntax. How to implement the sql? Thanks!

```
select * from couponcodes 
where ( couponcodes.subcatid in 
(select subcatid from Products where Products.prodid = 1012)
AND (couponcodes.couponcode = '5braceLets'))

OR 

Where  ( couponcodes.designerid in 
(select designerid from Products where Products.prodid = 1012)
AND (couponcodes.couponcode = '5dora'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `where` twice which is causing the syntax error. What you want to do is

```
select * from couponcodes 
where ( couponcodes.subcatid in 
(select subcatid from Products where Products.prodid = 1012)
AND (couponcodes.couponcode = '5braceLets'))
OR 
( couponcodes.designerid in 
(select designerid from Products where Products.prodid = 1012)
AND (couponcodes.couponcode = '5dora'))
```

Comment: okay, the syntax works. let me check on more field--expirationdate field in the couponcodes table...

Comment: I figured out the expiration date by adding:  AND couponcodes.expirationdate > GetDATE() ; I think your Answer will work. Thank you very much! I will mark your's as Answered soon...